# How to determine size of smaller objects to be removed?

Tags: bioinformatics, pixel, analysis, imagej, dependency-exclusion

How could I determine the size of the smaller objects to be removed from my image, I know by guessing this could work, for example to remove objects smaller than certain value, but is there more objective method?

I tried by guessing, but I know that there is a more precise method to do.

Comment: Which "size" are you talking about? Pixel size? Real size? Which programming language do you currently use? Please share the code involved, sample input, and the expected output

Comment: If this question assumes ImageJ and its macro language, it should then be indicated whether the images in question are binarized or not. If yes, the "Analyze Particles..."-mechanism may offer a valid approach that can then be further discussed. However, without detailed information about the kind of images and their objects, it will be near to impossible to provide reasonable help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: what is an object in your question ?  ... mmmmh didnt find a definition of object in any of imagej tutorial I browsed so far, so I guess an object is everything imagej tools could find/counts using a find/count object tool

Comment: It may be a good idea to first wait for the OP's reaction to my first comment -- no?

Comment: still waiting a reply to @NicoHaase question

Comment: then @herbie one